# why am getting the different output when using the concatenation statement in python merge for an xlsx files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, xlsx

I am trying to read 2 xlsx files and trying to append the data to a single xls file. Sample input :

data in f1 :

```
id na ln 
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2 
k1 k2 k3
```

data in f2 :

```
jd kd rd md nd pd  
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 f3
```

The first row is the column names. I used the below code to merge based on the columns.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df1 = pd.read_excel('f1.xlsx',usecols=[0,1,2],header=None)
 df2 = pd.read_excel('f2.xlsx',usecols=[0,4,5],header=None)
 merge_df = pd.concat([df1 ,df2])
```

When I execute this , I am getting the 5 columns , where as I am expecting 3 columns. If I create a new file from f2 with 3 columns and use usecols=[0,1,2] , I am getting 3 columns. What's wrong  in using different columns for the merge?

Hi, here is the print output  from merge_df

```
    0    1    2    4    5
0  id   na   ln  NaN  NaN
1  a1   b1   c1  NaN  NaN
2  a2   b2   c2  NaN  NaN
3  k1   k2   k3  NaN  NaN
0  jd  NaN  NaN   nd   pd
1  a1  NaN  NaN   e1   f1
2  a2  NaN  NaN   e2   f2
3  a3  NaN  NaN   e3   f3
```

```
   df2 : 
      0   4   5
  0  jd  nd  pd
  1  a1  e1  f1
  2  a2  e2  f2
  3  a3  e3  f3
```

Comment: There is no `pd.read`. Did you mean `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: Could you please try to make the data and the code a [mre], i.e. hard code the data into the code so that we can run and reproduce it easily? Also maybe post what you get and what you are expecting instead.

Comment: @ThomasWeller How does that apply? There are no column names since they used `header=None`.

Comment: Do you get what you expect if you do `print(df2)`?

Comment: @Barmar: sorry. Didn't read the code properly. I just read "The first row is the column names." so I thought the code would consider the column names. Otherwise the columns would become data.

Comment: @Barmar It seems the dupe wasn't that wrong, because the columns get the numbers from `usecols`

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed `df2`. That would confirm what @ThomasWeller said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns get the numbers that you use for importing. I.e. `df1` will have column "names" 0, 1 and 2. `df2` wil have column names 0, 4 and 5.

You want to rename the columns like so:

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns={4: 1, 5: 2})
```

This will give you the output

```
    0   1   2
0  id  na  ln
1  a1  b1  c1
2  a2  b2  c2
3  k1  k2  k3
0  jd  nd  pd
1  a1  e1  f1
2  a2  e2  f2
3  a3  e3  f3
```

This is probably still not what you want, since `id`, `na` and `ln` are the headers, because you wrote

> The first row is the column names.

You probably want something like

```py
df1 = pd.read_excel('f1.xlsx', usecols=[0, 1, 2], header=0)    # Use headers
df2 = pd.read_excel('f2.xlsx', usecols=[0, 4, 5], header=0)    # Use headers
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"jd": "id", "nd": "na", "pd":"ln"})  # Adapt headers to match
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use the `names` parameter to force a *default header* :

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('f1.xlsx', usecols=[0,1,2], header=None, names=range(3))
df2 = pd.read_excel('f2.xlsx', usecols=[0,4,5], header=None, names=range(3))

merge_df = pd.concat([df1 ,df2])
```

Output :

```
print(merge_df)

    0   1   2
0  id  na  ln
1  a1  b1  c1
2  a2  b2  c2
3  k1  k2  k3
0  jd  nd  pd
1  a1  e1  f1
2  a2  e2  f2
3  a3  e3  f3
```